# ListView doesn't get updated inside fragment until I re-start my application

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview, android-sqlite

My MainActivity implements a [PagerSlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip). So I have two tabs (CalculatorFragment and HistoryFragment). In the first one (CalculatorFragment), the user inputs information and clicks on a button that adds it to the database. The second tab (HistoryFragment) is supposed to list all of the items from the DB. The problem is that that list doesn't get updated until I re-start my application. I know why - because the list gets populated onCreateView only. My question is to how to fix this.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private TabsAdapter tabsAdapter;
private ViewPager viewPager;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(tabsAdapter);

    PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

    tabs.setViewPager(viewPager);

}}
```

Tab1

```
public class CalculatorFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calculator_layout, container, false);
        final DBTools dbTools = DBTools.getInstance(this.getActivity());

        //... the OnClickListener that adds all info to the database

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                //... code

                dbTools.insertRecord(queryValuesMap);
            }
        });
```

Tab2 with ListView

```
public class HistoryFragment extends Fragment {

    public static RecordArrayAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.history_layout, container, false);
        DBTools dbTools = DBTools.getInstance(this.getActivity());

        List<RecordObject> recordsList = dbTools.getAllRecords();

        Log.d("History-Fragment", recordsList.toString());

        if (recordsList.size() != 0) {

            ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.records_list);


            adapter = new RecordArrayAdapter(this.getActivity(), recordsList);

            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

RecordsArrayAdapter

```
public class RecordArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RecordObject> {

    SimpleDateFormat oldFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
    SimpleDateFormat newFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yy", Locale.US);

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    DBTools dbTools = new DBTools(this.getContext());

    public RecordArrayAdapter(Context context, List<RecordObject> objects) {
        super(context, 0, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.record_entry, parent, false);
        }

        RecordObject recordObject = getItem(position);

        TextView recordsID = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.key_id);

        TextView weight = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.weight);
        TextView reps = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.reps);
        TextView oneRM = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.onerm);
        TextView date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);

        newFormat.setLenient(false);
        try {
            date.setText(newFormat.format(oldFormat.parse(recordObject.getDate())));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        weight.setText(""+recordObject.getWeight());
        reps.setText(("'"+recordObject.getReps()));
        oneRM.setText(""+recordObject.getOneRM());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the fragment is in the selected tab, `setUserVisibleHint()` will be called with `true`, and when the fragment is not the selected tab, it will be called with `false`.

Add this method in `HistoryFragment`

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

    if (isVisibleToUser){
        DBTools dbTools = DBTools.getInstance(this.getActivity());
        List<RecordObject> recordsList = dbTools.getAllRecords();
        if (recordsList.size() != 0) {
            ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.records_list);
            adapter = new RecordArrayAdapter(this.getActivity(), recordsList);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
    else
        Log.d("HistoryFragment", "HistoryFragment is not visible.");
}
```

**NOTE** Define `View rootView` at class level, right now its in `onCreateView()`

Your fragment should look like this

```
public class HistoryFragment extends Fragment {

    public static RecordArrayAdapter adapter;
    View rootView = null;
    DBTools dbTools = null;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.history_layout, container, false);
        loadScreen();
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

        if (isVisibleToUser)
            loadScreen();
        else
            Log.d("HistoryFragment", "HistoryFragment is not visible.");
     }

    private void loadScreen(){
        dbTools = DBTools.getInstance(this.getActivity());
        List<RecordObject> recordsList = dbTools.getAllRecords();
        if (recordsList.size() != 0) {
            ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.records_list);
            adapter = new RecordArrayAdapter(this.getActivity(), recordsList);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hm, this didn't help. Still have to restart my app to see changes

Comment: I am sorry, I missed one line. Please try now.